# wpf usercontrol data-binding using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have wfp form like that:

```
public partial class MediaPlayerControlMain : Window
{
    MediaPlayerMain MediaPlayerMain;

    public MediaPlayerControlMain()
    {
        MediaPlayerMain = new MediaPlayerMain();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I have my user control (PlayList) that use MediaPlayerMain object.
That User Control have that:

```
public partial class PlayList : UserControl
{
    public MediaPlayerMain MediaPlayer
    {
        get { return (MediaPlayerMain)GetValue(MediaPlayerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MediaPlayerProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MediaPlayerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MediaPlayer", typeof(MediaPlayerMain), typeof(PlayList),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        );
```

}

Is there the way to set MediaPlayer property using just xaml. I tried to use "{Binding ElementName=MediaPlayerMain}" but it seems to be that MediaPlayerMain haven't initialized yet. Although i initialized it before InitializeComponent() function.  What am i doing wrong?. And what is the best option to pass this object to my user control?

Comment: Are there two objects of MediaPlayerMain class? One in main window and one in usercontrol? In first portion of code you create new object only within main window

Comment: No, there is only one object of MediaPlayerMain and User Control should use it. It is something like delegation.

Comment: can you please show the MediaPlayerMain  class.

Comment: I haven't finished it yet. And it's quite big to post it here. Probably I will post it on sourceforge.net or github or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class MediaPlayerControlMain : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        public MediaPlayerControlMain()
        {                
            InitializeComponent();
            MediaPlayerMain = new MediaPlayerMain();
        }
        private MediaPlayerMain mediaPlayerMain;

        public MediaPlayerMain MediaPlayerMain
        {
            get { return mediaPlayerMain; }
            set { mediaPlayerMain = value; Notify("MediaPlayerMain"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void Notify(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

        }
    }

 "{Binding MediaPlayerMain RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

The issue is you are trying to bind the field not property.For binding source must be the property not field because **binding system uses reflection and looks only for properties not for fields**.I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your root element (the Window/UserControl itself) in the markup. Ie:

```
<Window x:Name="mediaPlayer"
    ....>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty,ElementName=mediaPlayer}"
```

Comment: If he is not using MVVM this is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you setting the `DataContext` anywhere, and I don't think you have an object named `MediaPlayerMain` in your XAML tree

When you write `{Binding ElementName=MediaPlayerMain}`, you are telling WPF to set the property equal to the XAML object in the Visual Tree that is named `MediaPlayerMain`

What you're probably looking for instead is to bind to a Property in the DataContext named `MediaPlayerMain`, in which case your binding would look like this:

```
<local:PlayList MediaPlayer="{Binding MediaPlayerMain}" />
```

But that won't work unless your `DataContext` is set to an object containing the property `MediaPlayerMain`, such as setting `this.DataContext = this` in your Window's constructor.

As an alternative, you can use `ElementName` in your binding to tell WPF to look up the property on an object in the Visual Tree instead of in the `DataContext`, such as your `Window`.

```
<local:MediaPlayerControlMain x:Name="MainWindow" ...>
    <local:PlayList MediaPlayer="{Binding MediaPlayerMain, ElementName=MainWindow}" />
</local:MediaPlayerControlMain>
```

This will make your binding look for the property `MediaPlayerMain` in the XAML element named `MainWindow`, which is your `MediaPlayerControlMain` class.

If you're new to WPF's DataBinding, I actually have an article on my blog specifically for beginners that should help you understand better what it is and how it works: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Comment: Thank you, Rachel. I've read your article and it helped me to understand binding better.